# How can I keep my Rails controllers DRY and utilize my own API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, dry, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a controller called Books (and a corresponding Book model), and a controller called Users (and a corresponding User model). Each of these controllers has the standard CRUD actions, and they serve as the vehicle for my website's API as well.

Most of the pages on my site fit into this framework easily. For example, viewing a book. Or viewing your user account. Or editing your user account. Etc.

But let's say I have an index that will be somewhat unique: I want to show a list of users AND a list of books. This raises a few questions:

- What controller should this go under: UsersController, BooksController, or a new controller?
- If I create a new controller, is that considered a violation of any MVC principles since it won't be tied to any particular model in particular?
- How would this new controller action retrieve the data? If I write new ActiveRecord queries inside if it, them I'm repeating myself, since I already have code like this in my other controllers. I'd also prefer to consume my own API, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scopes(google search it) in your model to keep your controllers lean. Depending on what you want to show you can create a new method and view. lets say you have a user dashboard that list your books and the authors which are in seperate models.

you can create a new method called def dashboard inside your user controller since it relates to your user.

```
def dashboard

end
```

you would create a helper method in your model to scope the specific queries. Remember to also   add the proper route to your routes file.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Whichever you want.

1) I would probably write another controller, though it may end up to be a question of taste and it may change with the context of the application.

2) I would fetch the data from both models. There is no MVC rule mapping controllers and models one to one.

I am not quite sure what you mean by "queries" but you can put them in model methods (or scopes) to avoid DRY. Of course one gets tempted to do simple queries in controllers because ActiveRecord encaplulates them as methods (e.g. User.find(n) )